# Find/Replace text in a file using a batch file

Tags: text, batch-file, sed, replace

i need to replace a portion of a line of text with another line of text ex:

```
07/24/2012 06:30:00    <--what i start with
07/24/2012 06:30:00 Name=weather  <---is what i need it to look like
```

every day the date changes and i have about 20 of these lines to change every day, whats the easiest way to do this using a bat file, i want to be able to run it and it would open the file, change what needed to be changed then spit out the changed text file in another location. there are hundreds of lines in this text file that need to stay in the new one and not change only about 20 or so need to be changed. i dont need it to loop at all since every time i need to edit the file the text needed to change will be exactly the same and it will need to change the same number of lines each time. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

One way using `sed`:

```
sed -e "s/\(.*\)/\1 Name=weather/" file.txt > /your/new/location/newfile.txt
```

Perhaps you should update your question, to include example input and expected output. But the above line should get you started.